# IPB4 Where custom pages are stored?

Tags: ipb

Title pretty much tells everything. I'm unable to find where my created "custom page" is stored in Invision Power Board 4. Made it via its acp. Thanks for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

In IPB4 they are stored in the database, in separate tables for blocks and pages.

**cms_pages** - custom pages
**cms_blocks** - custom blocks

If you're intrested in modyfing them, refer to **block_content** and **page_content** columns. Remember to not include `<?php ?>` tags for your custom php blocks.

If you're looking to edit your custom **html page** in your favorite editor and don't copy paste the code in ACP at every update I may suggest a solution.

Create a new directory in FTP in your forum root, for example :

```
/custom/some_feature/
```

Create your target file inside :

```
/custom/some_feature/page.html
```

Paste this in to your custom page in ACP :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#main-container").load( "/custom/some_feature/page.html");
    });
</script>

<div id="main-container" style="min-height: 300px;"><div>
```

That's it, now you can edit your file in the FTP and it will be up to date on the forum.

You can go even further and setup a tool to **synchronize your local files** with the ftp automatically. If you are on **Windows** take a look at [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize).

For macOS and Linux there should be plenty of solutions as well.

Hope it helps, good luck!